# How to change the build version of SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, build-number

I installed the CU updates of August 2016 in SharePoint 2013 Server.

Updates were installed successfully but the build version is not updated.

It still shows old Version. Any ideas?

Comment: did u run the SP wizard? is it a farm > 2 server? Then run the wizard on every frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

build number is not supposed to be change after every cu. because every cu is not upgrading the schema of configuration database.

- check from central admin> upgrade and migration > patch status,on
  this page if the kb for August cu is listed that's mean it is
  installed.
- you can also check from add remove program from the server and then
  under sharepoint check if kb is listed there.

Here is great article which explain about build number myth.https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/

Answer (score 1):

Download SharePoint Server CU from Microsoft together with the .cab files. Copy them on all Servers in your farm and execute the .exe.

After the Installation is finished on all Servers, start the “SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard” on every Servers. (Do this step one Server after the other!)

You should now see the the build number in SharePoint. This article about build numbers could also be of interest for you:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/08/23/sharepoint-does-not-have-a-build-version-full-stop/

Answer (score -1):

Just download from this [site](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346) what version you need , after download run the file.

To check the version by using PowerShell cmd,

```
Get-SPFarm | select buildVersion
```

Comment: downloading version and installing is not the problem here